# Problem with creating a boxplot with given element in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a boxplot,  but I have a problem trying to understand the syntax. For now, this is my code

```
mydata = np.array([data['Adult_Card'], (data2[(data2['Fare_Type']=='Adult card fare') & (data2['Applicable_Time']=='All other timings')]['Fare_per_Ride']),
                 (data2[(data2['Fare_Type']=='Adult card fare') & (data2['Applicable_Time']=='Before 7.45am  (Weekdays excluding public holidays)')]['Fare_per_Ride']),
                 (data2[(data2['Fare_Type']=='Single trip') & (data2['Applicable_Time']=='All timings')]['Fare_per_Ride']),
                 (data['Adult_Cash'])])
labels = np.array(["Adult Card(Bus)","Adult Card(MRT)","Adult Card(Before 7.45am MRT)","Single Trip", "Adult Cash"])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation='vertical')
plt.title(title)
plt.xlabel('Distance(Km)')
plt.ylabel('Fares')
plt.legend(loc='upper left');
print(mydata)
plt.boxplot(mydata,labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

This is the value of mydata

```
[[ 83  93 103 113 122 129 135 139 143 147 151 155 159 163 167 171 175 178
  181 184 187 189 191 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205
  206 207 208]
 [ 83  93 103 113 122 129 135 139 143 147 151 155 159 163 167 171 175 178
  181 184 187 189 191 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205
  206 207 208]
 [ 33  43  53  63  72  79  85  89  93  97 101 105 109 113 117 121 125 128
  131 134 137 139 141 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155
  156 157 158]
 [150 170 170 170 190 190 190 210 210 230 230 230 230 240 240 240 240 250
  250 250 250 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260
  260 260 260]
 [150 170 170 170 190 190 190 210 210 230 230 230 230 240 240 240 240 250
  250 250 250 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260
  260 260 260]]
```

I want to create a boxplot by the array element, so

```
[ 83  93 103 113 122 129 135 139 143 147 151 155 159 163 167 171 175 178
  181 184 187 189 191 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205
  206 207 208]
```

will be the first box and subsequently. I am quite new to matplotlib so I dont really know whats wrong. This is the error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-31b9e5335060> in <module>
     32 print("Original data: " + str(data2.shape))
     33 print(mydata)
---> 34 plt.boxplot(mydata,labels=labels)
     35 plt.show()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in boxplot(x, notch, sym, vert, whis, positions, widths, patch_artist, bootstrap, usermedians, conf_intervals, meanline, showmeans, showcaps, showbox, showfliers, boxprops, labels, flierprops, medianprops, meanprops, capprops, whiskerprops, manage_xticks, autorange, zorder, data)
   2494         whiskerprops=whiskerprops, manage_xticks=manage_xticks,
   2495         autorange=autorange, zorder=zorder, **({"data": data} if data
-> 2496         is not None else {}))
   2497 
   2498 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1808                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1809                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1811 
   1812         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in boxplot(self, x, notch, sym, vert, whis, positions, widths, patch_artist, bootstrap, usermedians, conf_intervals, meanline, showmeans, showcaps, showbox, showfliers, boxprops, labels, flierprops, medianprops, meanprops, capprops, whiskerprops, manage_xticks, autorange, zorder)
   3501 
   3502         bxpstats = cbook.boxplot_stats(x, whis=whis, bootstrap=bootstrap,
-> 3503                                        labels=labels, autorange=autorange)
   3504         if notch is None:
   3505             notch = rcParams['boxplot.notch']

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in boxplot_stats(X, whis, bootstrap, labels, autorange)
   1179         labels = itertools.repeat(None)
   1180     elif len(labels) != ncols:
-> 1181         raise ValueError("Dimensions of labels and X must be compatible")
   1182 
   1183     input_whis = whis

ValueError: Dimensions of labels and X must be compatible
```

Update: I removed np.array() from my data and it works fine. I have none of explanation on why this fixes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I somehow missed the fact that `mydata` is a numpy array and not a list of lists...
To make your code work with the numpy array, you should use the transpose of mydata like so:

```py
###

plt.boxplot(mydata.T, labels=labels)

###
```

**Orinal post listed below**

---

Somewhere somehow your error report is inconsistent with your code. If I run the following code I definitely get a boxplot.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mydata = [
    [ 83, 93, 103, 113, 122, 129, 135, 139, 143,
      147, 151, 155, 159, 163, 167, 171, 175, 178,
      181, 184, 187, 189, 191, 193, 194, 195, 196,
      197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205,
      206, 207, 208], 
    [ 83, 93, 103, 113, 122, 129, 135, 139, 143,
      147, 151, 155, 159, 163, 167, 171, 175, 178,
      181, 184, 187, 189, 191, 193, 194, 195, 196,
      197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205,
      206, 207, 208], 
    [ 33, 43, 53, 63, 72, 79, 85, 89, 93, 97, 101,
      105, 109, 113, 117, 121, 125, 128, 131, 134,
      137, 139, 141, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148,
      149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157,
      158], 
    [150, 170, 170, 170, 190, 190, 190, 210, 210,
     230, 230, 230, 230, 240, 240, 240, 240, 250,
     250, 250, 250, 260, 260, 260, 260, 260, 260,
     260, 260, 260, 260, 260, 260, 260, 260, 260,
     260, 260, 260], 
    [150, 170, 170, 170, 190, 190, 190, 210, 210,
     230, 230, 230, 230, 240, 240, 240, 240, 250,
     250, 250, 250, 260, 260, 260, 260, 260, 260,
     260, 260, 260, 260, 260, 260, 260, 260, 260,
     260, 260, 260]
]
labels = np.array(["Adult Card(Bus)", "Adult Card(MRT)", "Adult Card(Before 7.45am MRT)", "Single Trip",  "Adult Cash"])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels,  rotation='vertical')
plt.title('title')
plt.xlabel('Distance(Km)')
plt.ylabel('Fares')
plt.legend(loc='upper left');
print(mydata)
plt.boxplot(mydata, labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

There are some other things going on that are not right, for instance I get a warning that there are "No handles with labels found to put in legend.", but maybe that is best asked in another question.

Comment: It works when i use python array instead of numpy array. I dont know why.

Comment: There is not supposed to be a legend there,  forgot about it thanks man!

Comment: D'oh! I totally missed the numpy part, but the fix is easy and I will make an edit to my original post!

Answer (score 1):

The [`boxplot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html) documentation states

> Make a box and whisker plot for each column of x or each vector in sequence x.

As a consequence, one needs to distinguish two cases

#### Sequence of vectors

Boxes are produced for each vector (i.e. a tuple, list, array) of a sequence (i.e. tuple, list).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[11, 21, 31, 41],  # box 1
        [12, 22, 32, 42],  # box 2
        [13, 23, 33, 43]]  # box 3

plt.boxplot(data)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This produces 3 boxes, each containing the data of each inner list. 
It allows to have vectors of differing length

```
data = [[11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61],
        [12, 22, 32],
        [13, 23, 33, 43]]
```

[image]

#### Array

If the input is a numpy array, it is interpreted **column-wise**, i.e. each column in the 2D array gets its own box.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[11, 21, 31, 41],
                 [12, 22, 32, 42],
                 [13, 23, 33, 43]])
#                 ^   ^   ^   ^
#           box   1   2   3   4

plt.boxplot(data)
plt.show()
```

[image]